# Why is my initializer list semi-ignored for type deduction?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, initializer-list, type-deduction

Consider the following code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Container, typename... Containers>
inline Container get_union(
    const Container& c1,
    const Containers&... more_containers)
{
    Container result(c1);
    auto f = [&result](const Container& c) {
        result.insert(std::begin(c), std::end(c)); 
    };
    [](...){}(( f(more_containers), 0)...);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m1 = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
    decltype(m1) m2 = get_union(m1, { {5, 6}, {7, 8} } );
    std::cout << "m2.size() = " << m2.size() << "\n'";
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build this, I [get](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f635c63938715916) (coliru link):

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:21:56: error: too many arguments to function 'Container get_union(const Container&, const Containers& ...) [with Container = std::unordered_map<int, int>; Containers = {}]'
     decltype(m1) m2 = get_union(m1, { {5, 6}, {7, 8} } );
                                                        ^
main.cpp:6:18: note: declared here
 inline Container get_union(
                  ^~~~~~~~~
```

Why is the compiler choosing the empty type-pack for Containers type, if that causes an error?

Comment: Not sure of the reason clang gives you that error but ask yourself, what is the type of `{ {5, 6}, {7, 8} }`?  How would you deduce what that is supposed to represent?

Comment: @NicolBolas The type is `Containers` which is not the same as the first parameter `Container`

Comment: @NathanOliver: I see.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) on cppreference:

> A braced-init-list is not an expression and therefore has no type, e.g. `decltype({1,2})` is ill-formed. Having no type implies that template type deduction cannot deduce a type that matches a braced-init-list, so given the declaration `template<class T> void f(T);` the expression `f({1,2,3})` is ill-formed.

---

> Why is the compiler choosing the empty type-pack for Containers type

Due to how template parameter packs can be ambiguous, there are two possible ways this could be interpreted (I think). Since neither is well-formed, I'm not sure if standard even dictates which interpretation is correct.

- Either the parameter pack has size 1 in which case that single type would be deduced from braced-init-list which is ill-formed.
- Or, since nothing with a type was passed beyond the first argument, an empty parameter pack is the only possible allowed deduced type for `Containers`. Now, since the deduced function only accepts a single argument, the braced-init-list is too much. This is how the compiler chose to interpret.

Fundamentally, the problem is that you're attempting a circular deduction. You're apparently trying to deduce `Containers` from something whose type would be deduced from whatever `Containers` is - if it wasn't an empty pack.

Comment: I was under the impression that initializer lists had their own type (`std::initializer_list`) - I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @einpoklum: That type does exist. However, they won't be deduced because: 1) it's not clear that this is what you actually wanted, and 2) in your case, it's not clear what the `T` in `initializer_list<T>` should be.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deduce from `{}` when calling a function.

```
template <typename Container, typename... Containers>
inline Container get_union(
  Container c1,
  std::initializer_list<Container> more_containers)
{
  for (auto&& c:more_containers)
    c1.insert( std::begin(c), std::end(c) );
  return c1;
}
```

then call like:

```
auto m2 = get_union(m1, { { {5, 6}, {7, 8} } } );
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7664ec6e03e528c1)

Comment: Should it be something like `const std::initializer_list<const Container&>& more_containers`?

Comment: @ein no, initializer lists hold values, not references.